# How to efficiently compress thousands of slightly differing JPEG files?

Tags: compression, image-compression

I captured a timelapse sequence from a camera, and saved it as a collection of separate `.jpg` files.

The files are numbering in the tens of thousands now, and most of them only differ by a slight amount - is there a compression method that would utilize this fact?

Since *video codecs* are more or less tailored towards compressing "sequences of slightly differing images", they seem like a good choice. However, as the files are already compressed, I would prefer not to lose any more information by further encoding them into a lossy format. So, I experimented with video formats that offer lossless compression like h264 or FFV1, but the resulting filesize was several times larger than a simple `gzip` of the `jpg` files - I assume it's because in the encoding step, the `jpg`s are converted to a bitmap, and *then* losslessly compressed, resulting in a better filesize than if I had a folder full of uncompressed bitmaps, but falling short of gzipping the original `jpg`s.

Right now, I'm simply storing them gzipped, but I wonder - is there is a better method, one that might exploit the fact that the files are perceptually very similar? Or, since the files are already compressed `jpg`s, the best way to go about this is to consider them no different from binary files - and use general purpose compression methods like gzip, bzip, etc.?

(Also, apologies for asking on StackOverflow - there might be a better StackExchange site, but I couldn't find any.)

Comment: (No expert) I don't see many options without pretty complex coding. I second your assumption about the observation (ffv1 and co.). gzipping jpg's sounds like a pretty bad idea, which might even make the files bigger (at least lzma2 would detect these cases and switch automatically to no-comp). If that works for you, your jpeg-encoders entropy-compr is strange. The only *relatively doable compression* i see is recompressing jpegs. This will save bytes, but *not exploit similarity* (independent compr). e.g. Dropbox' [Lepton](https://github.com/dropbox/lepton)

Comment: If you got some months to spare, you can of course try to apply the ideas from lepton / packjpg / google's project (where i forgot the name) **edit: brunsli** targeted towards your case which also means: inverting parts of jpg (e.g. entropy coder step) and then building a joint statistical-model. But well... that will be hard.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define "slightly differing". It seems that you are demanding lossless compression of the JPEGs, even though each of the JPEGs was compressed with loss. Anyway, depending on how slight the differences are, it might be effective to send the first JPEG, and then PNGs (which are lossless) of the difference between successive images, pixel-by-pixel. If at some point the next PNG is bigger than the JPEG being differenced, then just send the JPEG. That way your stream at least won't get bigger.

If the sequence of images have effectively panning or zooming as part of the difference, then this won't work so well, since pixels in the same locations in the images are differenced. For panning and zooming, you would want a video format. Accepting a little loss goes a long way.